# PostgreSQL - Flatten data - Crosstab function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, flatten

(first post sorry if i did something wrong)

I would like to flatten some normalized data i have and i struggle with crostab function.

Background:

- I imported in my pgsql db a file containing historical drilling data (i'm geologist).
  following screenshot of the headers. As you can it's flat data. table name = wadl4_a117888
  [Historic data headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ivKL.png)

Because i will have to import other historic dataset with different header but similar data (example: litho1 from file A and geol1 from file B).
I want to 'translate/standardize' the headers and have all the data together.

- So i normalized the data using a view. table view name = tblvw_wadl4_a117888_norm
  [historic data normalized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPC7i.png).
  Note: 'pfield' = pivoted field and 'pvalue' = pivoted value
- Then i 'translated' the historical headers into the wanted ones. 'field_sgq' = the wanted headers.

[translation table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Duj.png)

Now i would like to flatten this table (see previous screenshot). Keeping as 'key' the fields datasource, hole_ID, depth_from, depth_to.

Final result:
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfUqg.png).

I tried using case when for every wanted header, but created multiple rows for the same 'key' (holeid, depth_from, depth_to). Also tried to use crosstab function but doesn't obtain the wanted results.

Thank you for your help !
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Following is sample code which you can modify as it does not include all possible columns which you might have. I have used field_orig column instead of field_sgq column because it has null values in sample data you have shown in screenshot.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMPTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPTable
(
    datasource TEXT,
    holdeid TEXT
    ,depth_from NUMERIC
    ,depth_to NUMERIC
    ,field_orig TEXT
    ,field_sgq TEXT
    ,pvalue TEXT
);

INSERT INTO TEMPTable VALUES ('wadl4_a117888','WRVAC065',0.00,3.00,'projectcode','project','Yilgarn'),
('wadl4_a117888','WRVAC065',0.00,3.00,'weath','Weathering','5'),
('wadl4_a117888','WRVAC065',0.00,3.00,'clr1','Lith1_Color1','BN'),
('wadl4_a117888','WRVAC065',0.00,3.00,'clr2','Lith1_Color2','OR'),
('wadl4_a117889','WRVAC065',0.00,2.00,'projectcode','project','YilgarnT'),
('wadl4_a117889','WRVAC065',0.00,2.00,'weath','Weathering','2'),
('wadl4_a117889','WRVAC065',0.00,2.00,'clr1','Lith1_Color1','BNT'),
('wadl4_a117889','WRVAC065',0.00,2.00,'clr2','Lith1_Color2','ORY');

SELECT * FROM crosstab('select datasource,holdeid,depth_from,depth_to,field_orig,pvalue from TEMPTable',  $q$ values ('projectcode'),('weath'),('clr1'),('clr2') $q$)
             AS ct (datasource TEXT,
    holdeid TEXT
    ,depth_from NUMERIC
    ,depth_to NUMERIC,projectcode TEXT, weath TEXT, clr1 TEXT, clr2 TEXT);
```

Comment: thank you @sandeep for your answer. i will have a try.

Comment: hello @sandeep.  sorry for the (very) late answer.
it worked!! thank you very much for your help